# Previous opened forms are showing in Customized Powerapps forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-portal, powerapps-canvas

I have created Newform, Edit Form, and View Form for a SharePoint List in the PowerApps (Separate Forms for each mode).

So whenever I click any of the forms, the previously opened form is showing initially for 2 - 3 seconds, and then the respective form is showing.

any solution would be helpful. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: For Modern experience, you just need one Form for New, Edit and View Mode. See this Video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Badj3_T8zAw

Comment: my requirement is like that , i have some extra items in edit and view forms